# Cannot list user's directories android

Tags: android, directory

My problem is that when I call

```
dir.listFiles()
```

on a directory, user's folders (like DCIM, Ringtones, Downloads, ecc..) are not shown, so  folders like

```
 /sdcard
```

or similars seems to be empty, but when i check them with ES File Explorer the directories are perfectly shown.

Please help me!

I am working in API 24

Comment: Have you requested the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission at runtime?

Comment: what is the `dir`/ what is it's path?

Comment: @earthw0rmjim, why you think that this permission should be requested at runtime?

Comment: @VladMatvienko because the `protectionLevel` of that permission is `dangerous`, so it needs to be requested at runtime. Take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: @earthw0rmjim, that was something new for me, before I thought that only WRITE has to be requested.

Comment: @VladMatvienko there isn't one single path, every path which contains user folders simply results as empty.

Comment: @earthw0rmjim i requested it in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @LucaOrlandi, that is not the runtime permissions. You have to request the runtime permission.

Comment: @VladMatvienko How do i do that?

Comment: well, first you use search, and then, aproximately in 15 seconds you find the solution.

Comment: @VladMatvienko Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @VladMatvienko i solved the issue
I just requested the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions at runtime, so that the user will be asked to grant the permission, now it works like a charm!

Link: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html